# How much minimum memory do I need to run Elasticsearch with docker in 3 node cluster mode?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

My budget is not enough So I want to use t3a.small AWS ec2 instance for running Elasticsearch

Question is, t3a.small provides 2GiB memory,

which I wonder would it be enough for running elasticsearch in 3 node cluster mode

with docker-compose.

I want to run FastAPI, SpringBoot application, Airflow, Redis all wrapped in docker container

on same t3a.small instance, so I'm worried about memory shortage issues. Can I get some advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run Elasticsearch on a 2 gig node, ie 1 gig of heap. generally we'd suggest running 2 gig of heap on a 4 gig node as a min for production

Comment: so your saying t3a.small instance is not enough for 3 node cluster?

Comment: not all 3 on the one instance. it should work with 1 node per instance, ie 3 instances, but it's not ideal